# How to split up ListView into parts, so you can treat split parts as separate ListViews?

Tags: android, android-listview, commonsware-cwac

What would be a way of doing this, or the best way to do this? For example I would want to split mListMain, into mList1, mList2, mList3 and be able to set separate Long Click listeners, listitem listeners and context menus for each. Something like mList1.setlistitemclicklistener, registercontextmenu.(mList2)...

The reason I want to know how to do this, if it's even possible, is that I've merged multiple ListView's arrays using mergeAdapter from CommonGuy, but now since it's all one list, none of the things I set for the separate lists remain, like context menus and onitemclicklisteners.

Comment: If you want them to scroll together look into ItemTypeCount() methods in an Adapter. If not, use separate listviews in a linear layout with separate adapters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> none of the things I set for the separate lists remain, like context menus and onitemclicklisteners

You are welcome to set up item-click and item-long-click listeners for the `ListView`. However, you will have to interpret the `position` properly, to determine what sub-list the position pertains to, so you can decide what to do on those events.

Comment: Eventually was forced to go with this, while not the easiest solution, it does work and thank you for your mergeadapter library.

Comment: @I'm_With_Stupid: An `Adapter` cannot readily address the problem directly, because the things you are dealing with are at the widget level. Someone could write a `MergeListView` that has a `MergeAdapter`-like API and also allows you to set up listeners for each segment (view or adapter) that is being merged into the whole. I'm glad that `MergeAdapter` is working for you!

Answer (score 1):

You can add list views as part of views of list view

so there is parent list view whose adaptor's getView returns child list view .
This will you can multiple list view part of one parent list view

Comment: This isn't an expandable ListView right? Also any examples of how to do this?

Comment: you can use expandable list view as well. It is better to use expandable list view if you know what you are doing. here is sample code for expandable list view http://www.codota.com/android/scenarios/52fcbd77da0a085556555e59/android.widget.ExpandableListView?tag=dragonfly

Comment: I would like to know how to do it without an expandable ListView, is it possible?

Comment: as I said, write a sample list view with adaptor. You can start with just texview. Replace the getview of adaptor to create another list view. here is the example of simple array adaptor http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html use this and inside get view add another list view

Comment: Oh, I see what your saying.